# Soft Cross Entropy to increase precision?

Tags: cross-entropy, softmax

Okay, so lets say that I have a network that is predicting a distribution of the depth of single laser point from some other data. We could regress on the ground truth directly, or in my case, map the ground truth to a discretized space.

For example: N=5, where each block - represents 0.2m

[0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1]

Then if the ground truth specifies 0.3m, we would build a digitized label set of [0 1 0 0 0], and apply cross entropy loss. But now i have lost some precision. I was hoping that we can instead have a label of [0.5 0.5 0 0 0], and train this on some kind of soft cross entropy loss.

But my toy example here shows that it doesnt work:

```
x = torch.tensor(
    np.array([
        [0,0.5,0.5,0,0]
    ]).astype(np.float32)
)

label_soft = torch.tensor(
    np.array([
        [0,0,1,0,0] 
    ]).astype(np.float32)
)
# 1.3401 - [0,0.5,0.5,0,0]

label_soft = torch.tensor(
    np.array([
        [0,1,0,0,0] 
    ]).astype(np.float32)
)
# 1.3401 - [0,0.5,0.5,0,0]


# My Loss
x_softmax = F.softmax(x,dim=1)
loss = -torch.sum(label_soft * torch.log(x_softmax), 1)
loss = torch.mean(loss)
print(loss)
```

Assuming here that the network output is [0,0.5,0.5,0,0], no matter how i change my soft label to better match the network output, the cost doesnt change. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Categorical cross-entropy is about unordered, categorical outcomes.  But if the laser penetrates 0.3m, this implies it is also true that the laser penetrated 0.2m, right? So it sounds like you have an *ordered* problem. It seems like using a method that respects your ordered categories would be more appropriate. But I'm not sure why you're discretizing  your data, since this will naturally discard information about your lasers and make the model less precise.

Comment: I'm with @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica. I think you have a regression problem, not classification. Fortunately, neural nets can do regression.

Comment: no i want the network to learn a multimodal distribution..not just regress the value

Comment: Do you mean you want to learn a "multinomial" distribution? Why? What problem are you trying to solve? How does using "soft cross entropy" solve that problem?